# How can I mount a single distinct Secret into each Pod managed by a StatefulSet?

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset, kubernetes-statefulset

I have 3 different Kubernetes Secrets and I want to mount each one into its own Pod managed by a StatefulSet with 3 replicas.

Is it possible to configure the StatefulSet such that each Secret is mounted into its own Pod?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. A StatefulSet (and any workload controller for that matter) allows only a single pod definition template (it could have multiple containers). The issue with this is that a StatefulSet is designed to have N replicas so can you have an N number of secrets. It would have to be a SecretStatefulSet: a different controller.

Some solutions:

- You could define a single [Kubernetes secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) that contains all your required secrets for all of your pods. The downside is that you will have to share the secret between the pods. For example:

  ```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: Secret
  metadata:
    name: mysecret
  type: Opaque
  data:
    pod1: xxx
    pod2: xxx
    pod3: xxx
    ...
    podN: xxx
  ```
- Use something like [Hashicorp's Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) and store your secret remotely with keys such as `pod1`, `pod2`, `pod3`,...`podN`. You can also use an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module). This seems to be the more solid solution IMO but it might take longer to implement.

In all cases, you will have to make sure that the number of secrets matches your number of pods in your StatefulSet.

Comment: Thanks, yeah thought as much - ironically I'm trying to run Hashicorp Vault/Consul, but will use something like you suggested

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you're looking for I guess. https://github.com/spoditor/spoditor

Essentially, it uses a custom annotation on the `PodSpec` template, like:

```
      annotations:
        spoditor.io/mount-volume: |
          {
            "volumes": [
              {
                "name": "my-volume",
                "secret": {
                  "secretName": "my-secret"
                }
              }
            ],
            "containers": [
              {
                "name": "nginx",
                "volumeMounts": [
                  {
                    "name": "my-volume",
                    "mountPath": "/etc/secrets/my-volume"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
```

Now, `nginx` container in each Pod of the StatefulSet will try to mount its own dedicated secret in the pattern of `my-secret-{pod ordinal}`.

You will just need to make sure `my-secret-0`, `my-secret-1`, so on and so forth exists in the same namespace of the StatefulSet.

There're more advanced usage of the annotation in the documentation of the project.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I've added detailed description how it helps.

Comment: Thanks to you for taking the time to fix.